# Unusual series of events

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

If you are alert, you might clearly see an object in your imagination when you read the sentence:

"It lasted only from CTScan to Face Palm."

What is the object?

Answer (score 2):

The object could be:

> Bottle

Reasoning:

> Last letters of "It lasted only from CTScan to Face Palm." in reverse are: M E O N M Y D T or "Me on my DT". DT can stand for delerium tremens - a symptom of withdrawal. I connect it to alcohol, so bottle. However It could be withdrawal of something else or DT could stand for defensive tackle in football or school detention, so I think I am still missing something...I think there is a reason for CTS and FP being capital letters, but do not understand it yet.

Comment: Thanks for trying ! Not the intended answer:)

Answer (score 0):

The object appears to be

> A football (probably rugby, possibly american)

Because

> The last letters of each word including the last sentence spells out: td ym no em t set - or (TD I'm No Empty Set). An empty set would be {}. So, my conclusion would be that it is (), or the shape of a football. I only say possibly american because I don't see any laces.

Comment: Thanks for trying ! Not the intended answer:)

Comment: Yup. I noticed that after the other person posted. Mine went past the quoted sentence. My bad.